# laravel and nginx downloading files

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

laravel and nginx downloading files,I try it like this:

`TestController.php`，passing variables to view:

```
public function test()
{
    $filepath = '2017/demo.zip';
    $filename = 'demo.zip';

    return view('download', compact('filepath','filename'));
}
```

`download.blade.php`，receiving the variables：

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= {{$filename}}");
header('X-Accel-Redirect: /down/'. {{$filepath}} );
exit;
?>
```

**Questions：**
1、Is the content of `download.blade.php` right? Or this file is not necessary？
2、If `download.blade.php` is necessary，but the variables in `{{ }}`  can not  be parsed, how to write it?

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to render view. you can use laravel response helper:

`return response()->download(public_path('path_to_directory/demo.zip'));`